# Finding a difference in values for set of values in a different column

Tags: r

I am trying to find difference in the first and last value of for a set of values in a given column in R. The example data table is

```
V1 V2
A  2
B  4
A  3
C  1
D  2
B  4
A  5
```

The output should take the first and last occurrence and give the result

```
V1 V2
A  3
B  0
C  1
D  2
```

I am confused as to which function to use to get to the result in r.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise(V2 = if(n()>1) last(V2)- first(V2) else V2)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#     V1    V2
#   <chr> <int>
#1     A     3
#2     B     0
#3     C     1
#4     D     2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `aggregate` from base R,

```
aggregate(V2 ~ V1, df, FUN = function(i) ifelse(length(i) > 1, tail(i, 1) - head(i, 1), i))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   V1 V2
> 1  A  3
> 2  B  0
> 3  C  1
> 4  D  2
> ```

**DATA**

```
dput(df)
structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), V2 = c(2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 5L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```